# Writing the network part of a C program

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I have begun writing (in C) a small client/server application which relies on TCP.  I lack any experience in network programming.  I'm sorry for the open-ended character of this post.

I'm wondering how best to encode and decode messages.  I've chosen the following approach:

The client sends commands to the server.  Every command has a number assigned to it and a struct.  The struct stores the command's arguments and the way the arguments are laid out in memory (and in the stream as well).  When the client wants to send a command, it fills the respective struct with data.  In order for the server to recognize the command, the client sends one byte which contains the command number.  Right after the command number byte, the message itself is fed to the stream (with its fields properly converted to network byte order).

This approach led to working code, but it entails a lot of redundancy (I find myself writing switch statements over and over).  Is there a better way?  What's the standard procedure?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? TCP is a stream protocol, not datagram based.

Comment: can you post the relevant code? It'll give a better picture of your problem.

Comment: On rereading my message, I noticed it's fairly unspecific.  I'll improve it.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov: OP is talking about implementing his own application protocol, not a transport protocol.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs But what he wants to invide sits on top of either TCP or UDP. And while he wants to use TCP, he talks about datagrams, so he has to make provisions for this.

Comment: @glglgl, well indeed, question is not very clear on this.

Comment: If the OP needs some reliable application-level protocol, then why not use the CURL library and HTTP as a transport without going deep into the layer-3 details ?

Comment: Consider using a text-based protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are a nice way to serialize/deserialize data. There are implementations for C.

Comment: Thank you very much.  However I've begun writing this program in order to teach myself socket programming, so I would like to get as far as possible without reverting to libraries.